# Java/html input type radio - Parameters missmatch

Tags: java, html, spring, parameters, web

I am completely new to html and that stuff.

I try to create a webpage (using Java/Spring Boot) where the user views a "Pizza", selects an amount and size and submits the order.

The specific part of the html document:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Bestellmenge:</span>
    <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="1"/>
</div>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="pizzaSize" value="1"> Klein</input>
    <input type="radio" name="pizzaSize" value="2"> Mittel</input>
    <input type="radio" name="pizzaSize" value="3"> Gross</input>
</form>
<div>
    <form th:action="@{/saveOrderAndReload(name=${pizza.name}, amount=${amount}, size=${pizzaSize})}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" value="zur Bestellung hinzufuegen"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So when the user presses the button, the following method gets called:

```
    @RequestMapping("saveOrderAndReload")
    public String saveOrderAndReload(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam int size, @RequestParam int amount, Model model) {
    //Do whateher
    return "another html page";
    }
```

From my understanding, the method needs String, int, int as parameters. The webpage delivers String (the pizza name), int (from the input field) and int from the radio input (is that right?)

However, when trying to execute, the method gets called like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/saveOrderAndReload?name=SalamiPizza&amount=&size=
```

Missing the 2 parameters, getting me the following error:

```
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Comment: It will do nothing. All your form elements are outside the form... Your `th:action` should only be `/saveOrderAndReload` and everything else should come from inside your form. You aren't calling am method you are submitting data to a URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of Thymeleaf and how the web works is flawed.

First all of your elements need to be inside the same `<form>` to be submitted (unless you hack around with JavaScript but that is a different beast). From HTML (nor Thymeleaf) you will call a method you submit data to a URL (which eventually in your case will execute the controller).

Now with that knowledge first fix your form.

```
<div>
    <form th:action="@{/saveOrderAndReload(name=${pizza.name}, amount=${amount}, size=${pizzaSize})}" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Bestellmenge:</span>
            <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group>
            <input type="radio" name="pizzaSize" value="1"> Klein</input>
            <input type="radio" name="pizzaSize" value="2"> Mittel</input>
            <input type="radio" name="pizzaSize" value="3"> Gross</input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" value="zur Bestellung hinzufuegen"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Next your `th:action` doesn't need to include any values (unless you want to still pass the name). So change it to `th:action="@{/saveOrderAndReload(name=${pizza.name})` all the other properties will be included in the form.

You have named your radio button `pizzaSize` and not size, either change the name of the parameter in your controller to `pizzaSize` or change the name of the radio buttons to `size` either way will work.

Assuming you change your radio button names your form should look like this.

```
<div>
    <form th:action="@{/saveOrderAndReload(name=${pizza.name})}" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Bestellmenge:</span>
            <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group>
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="1"> Klein</input>
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="2"> Mittel</input>
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="3"> Gross</input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" value="zur Bestellung hinzufuegen"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense. I did all the changes to the code and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

All params in your request are string. You should make them integers manually. I'm not familiar with java, but I think it should be like

```
public String saveOrderAndReload(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String sizeString, @RequestParam String amountString, Model model) {
    int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeString);
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountString);
```

You also need some portion of code to check, if strings are empty - set 0 for your int-values.

Comment: No you don't. Would be kind of a lousy framework if the conversion wouldn't be done for you...